# ATtiny2313 external 2 MHz crystal

Tags: capacitor, crystal, attiny, fuse-bits

I would like to run my ATtiny2313 from an external 2 MHz crystal, but I'm unsure how. I have seen images and examples where there are capacitors connected to ground after the crystal. Like this:

[image]

But I don't understand how to decide the size of the capacitors.

Also, when I used the internal 2 MHz, I burned the bootloader via the Arduino IDE, but the lowest my board manager has is a 4 MHz external clock. So I'm also unsure about how to set the fuses to run with an external 2 MHz clock. Can I just use the bootloader based on a 4 MHz clock and define F_CPU as 2 MHz in my code?

Comment: The capacitor values can be taken from the IC manufacturer's datasheet.

Comment: Actually datasheet contains a suitable range only, datasheet does not tell a formula how to calculate them, as that is presented in a separate application note. The question rather is, if it is so hard to make the software environment to use 2 MHz clock, does it make any sense then. Why do you want to use 2 MHz crystal, and you need to know which exact capacitance load rating the crystal has before you even know if it will work with the ATTiny.

Answer (score 2):

## Capacitor Selection

You may be interested in Microchip's application note (AN2519) that has some additional information:

[AVR® Microcontroller Hardware Design Considerations](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/AN2519-AVR-Microcontroller-Hardware-Design-Considerations-00002519B.pdf)

It has the following sections which apply to your questions about crystals:

> - 5. Using Crystal and Ceramic Resonators
>
>   - 5.1. Selecting the Clock Source in the AVR MCU
>   - 5.2. About Crystals and Ceramic Resonators
>   - 5.3. Recommended Capacitor Values
>   - 5.4. Unbalanced External Capacitors
>   - 5.5. RTC Crystals
>   - 5.6. PCB Layout
> - 6. Unused XTAL Pins

The [ATtiny2313 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2543-AVR-ATtiny2313_Datasheet.pdf) provides some recommended values as well:

[image: Table 4. Crystal Oscillator Operating Modes]
<sup>*(page 24)*</sup>

Check the datasheet for the crystal you are using as well for what its loading capacitance is.

## Clocking

The ATtiny2313 has an internal 8 MHz RC oscillator. By default, the MCU runs at 1 MHz from its internal 8 MHz clock (not 2 MHz as you mentioned):

> The device is shipped with CKSEL = "0100", SUT = "10", and CKDIV8 programmed. The default clock source setting is the Internal RC Oscillator with longest start-up time and an initial system clock prescaling of 8, resulting in 1.0 MHz system clock.

See the following tables for selecting a clock source and setting relevant fuse bits:

[image: Table 2. Device Clocking Select]
<sup>*(page 23)*</sup>

[image: Table 67. Fuse Low Byte]
<sup>*(page 160)*</sup>

To use an external 2 MHz crystal, you'll want to set **CKSEL3..0** = `1010` and **CKDIV8** = `1` (unprogrammed, to disable division by 8).

**CKSEL3..1** being set to `101` (second row of table 4) means that it will correspond to a frequency between 0.9 and 3.0 MHz. The **CKSEL3..0** values `1000`-`1111` (fifth row of table 2) correspond to an external crystal. It's confusing because you have to check multiple locations throughout the datasheet to compile this information.

(Leave **SUT1..0** as `10` unless for some reason you need to modify the start-up time or use brown-out detect.)

---

As for your bootloader/firmware needs, you'll want to ask that as a separate question; I've only attempted to address the hardware requirements here. *(This is why you should only ask one question at a time.)*